# MySQL Timestamp trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, timestamp

I am trying to set a trigger to record a timestamp in a log table when the main table is updated. I have a main table called cm and have a log table with a timestamp column.

The timestamp column in the log table is set up as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE log ADD COLUMN modified_timestamp TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

The trigger I trying is as follows but throws this error "Error Code 1193. Unknown system variable 'modified_timestamp'

Trigger:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `ahrq cm`.`table_timestamp` BEFORE UPDATE ON `ahrq    cm`.`ahrq_inventory_all`
FOR EACH ROW begin

set log.modified_timestamp=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();

end
//
```

Can anyone shed light on this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trigger should update the `log` table using a normal SQL command:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `ahrq cm`.`table_timestamp` BEFORE UPDATE ON `ahrq cm`.`ahrq_inventory_all`
FOR EACH ROW begin

INSERT INTO log (modified_timestamp) VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP());

end
//
```

Comment: Thanks, that succesfully created the trigger but when I ran an insert into the DB nothing was recorded in the log table.

Comment: Realized my own mistake, I needed another trigger for 'insert'. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

set is used for setting value of variables (user, system, or stored routine variables).

To update field in the log table need to issue a UPDATE query, such as

```
UPDATE log SET modified_timestamp = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() WHERE ...
```